# Prompt is not shown after running a script with an "exec" command redirecting stdout and stderr

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, exec

An example script is shown below.

The meaning of the syntax - `exec > >(tee -a "$file" "$sec_file") 2>&1` , is to print to the console the `stdout` and `sdterr` , and also to print to the files - `/tmp/log.txt`  the `stdout` and `sdterr`

```
more /tmp/ppl
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/log.txt
sec_file=/tmp/log1.txt

exec > >(tee -a "$file" "$sec_file") 2>&1

echo "linux server is up "
```

but when I run the script as

```
bash /tmp/ppl
```

it prints

```
linux server is up
```

but then my prompt isn't shown. The prompt only appears after I press <kbd>enter</kbd>

I am testing this on RHEL 7.5 and my bash version is `4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Let's continue  [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111533/discussion-on-question-by-yael-bash-script-is-hang-when-using-exec-in-the-srcrip).

Comment: Does the problem occur with the script shown in your question or only with a different script that may contain more than `echo "linux server is up "`?

Comment: It's shown but it's show *before* `tee` writes its output as `tee` here is started in background and not waited for by `bash`. There are a number of Q&As that discuss that here. We can probably close this one as a duplicate of some of them.